# Cross-platform support for various MFC\ATL classes

Tags: c++, mfc, cross-platform, atl

I'm trying to keep my C++ project cross-platform as much as possible.
Albeit I do have dependencies on the following MFC\ATL classes: **CString, CTime, CTimeSpan**.

Is there an open implementation somewhere of MFC\ATL classes?
How common are these packages and should I use the open source libraries to start with, or should I wait until the need arises?

Comment: Consider porting to Qt instead, as a side benefit Qt is much nicer to work.

Comment: @Paulo: seriously? Convert an entire project to a Qt project and the Qt build system just for these 3 classes?

Comment: If it is not GUI why use MFC and not plain STL? If it is GUI and he wants to be cross platform, porting to Qt is the easiest way for c++.

Comment: I'm going to use a managed language for the GUI. Python would probably be most portable, if I'll only figure out the extending\embedding hell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `CString` use `std::string`

Instead of `CTime` use `boost::ptime`

Instead of `CTimeSpan` use `boost::time_duration`

Answer (score 2):

While this proposal won't answer your cross platform requirement, it does meet the request for an "open implementation of MFC/ATL classes".

Check out the Windows Template Library(WTL).

Microsoft open sourced it some years ago, you can download it from its [sourceforge project page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/), and it's also available from Microsoft's website somewhere.

The description from the SourceForge page:
Windows Template Library (WTL) is a C++ library for developing Windows applications and UI components. It extends ATL (Active Template Library) and provides a set of classes for controls, dialogs, frame windows, GDI objects, and more.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not to rely in those classes. They are specific of MFC/ATL, and won't be easily ported to Unixes, for example. Try to build a separate conversion layer, and try to build around [boost](http://www.boost.org) libraries, much more portable.